# Can I have a modem/router going to 2 computers then also have another router going to 2 other computers with all getting internet

Tags: networking, router, internet, pfsense

I have a modem/router in one, and it's going to 2 computers itself. Then I have an Ethernet cable going to an unmanaged switch, then from the switch going to 2 different computers. All have Ethernet connection.

I have a PfSense router as my 2nd router and one of the 2nd computers are that router.

Can I have internet going thought both routers and have my main computer which is the other computer on my switch going through my PfSense? So modem/router to 2 computers getting internet from that. Then from that modem/router to an unmanaged switch to PfSense to my main computer.

I only want my Main computer going through my PfSense. Is this possible? Can I only have 1 computer going through PfSense, or does everything have to go through it?

I don't want to set up PfSense to everything because it's in one room with my main computer, nothing else is in here.

Comment: You can put a 4 or 8 port switch immediately after your modem / router and hook everything to that and all will have internet. Or if feasible, you can put your pfsense computer right after the modem / router and feed that to a switch. Hook everything up to that.

Comment: Explain in detail what this "*PfSense router*" is. Is it more than just a "*router*"? Does it include a wireless access point (e.g. WiFi capability)? Does it have a built-in switch (e.g. several LAN ports besides its WAN port)?

Comment: Sawdust- It is actually a Proxmox machine that has a VM PfSense it has 1 mobo LAN port and 2 NIC LAN port, and I'm using 1 NIC LAN port to my main computer to use Proxmox. No AP I will be using my modem/router as an AP. it has 4 LAN ports and my main computer has 2 LAN ports. I just want my main computer traffic to go through my PfSense router and everything else go to my main router.